# Calculating $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{e^{i \theta}} d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

**The question**:

> Calculate $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{e^{it}} dt$.

**My attempt**:

Notice that $e^{it}$ is the unit circle and we seek the integral of the image of that circle of the exponent function. I found something similar but it didn't helped. Maybe it can be improved:

Let $\gamma$ be the path $z(t)=e^{it}$, $t\in[0,2\pi]$ and $f(z)=e^z$.
$$ \int _\gamma f(z)dz=\int _0^{2\pi}f(z(t))\cdot\dot{z}(t)= \int_0^{2\pi}e^{e^{it}}ie^{it}dt
\\ [u=e^{it}, du=ie^{it}dt]
\\=\int_1^1e^udu=0
$$

Comment: There is something wrong. The result shall be $2\pi$

Comment: In my attampt I tried to solve something similar with the hope it will help somehow. This is a different integral. @VonNeumann

Comment: Wait, is your work for your integral or for a different problem?

Comment: For the integral @cmk

Comment: The work you showed is not the same as the problem you were given. They're clearly different integrals.

Comment: Ok. I just don't know how to calculate it so I tried something different and now I see it doesn't help. I'm looking for some other direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On unit circle
$$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{e^{it}} dt=\int_{|z|=1} e^{z} \dfrac{dz}{iz}=\dfrac{1}{i}\int_{|z|=1} \dfrac{e^{z} dz}{z}=2\pi$$

Comment: Why does $\int _{|z|=1}{e^z \over z} dz = 2\pi i$?

Comment: @J.Doe By Cauchy integral formula or residue theorem.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without any complex analysis, starting with $$e^{e^{it}}
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^{int}}{n!}.$$